# Joomla 4 and 5 support for legacy classes and methods

Tags: joomla-4.x, jfactory, deprecated

I am transferring custom code to joomla 4.

Are the legacy classes such as `JFactory` supported and if so for how long?

Where can I find documentation on this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, most of J-prefixed classes can still be used. They were scheduled to be removed in 5.0 but due to release cycle changes the removal has been postponed to 6.0. Instead the code for creating class aliases has been moved to Backward Compatibility plugin. You can read more about it in the [manual](https://manual.joomla.org/migrations/44-50/compat-plugin/).

Comment: It looks like JError may not be supported. I get `Class "JError" not found` when using `JError::raiseError`

Comment: JError was removed in 4.0. You can see more in `..\libraries\legacy\error\error.php` of your Joomla 3 instance around line #52. `@deprecated  4.0 Will be removed without replacement`.

Comment: If I read this PR correctly, error handling will be done differently in the future: 
 https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/41809